# Adobe Flex: hiding tab bar in tabNavigator

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, hide, tabbar, tabnavigator

Does anyone know how to hide the tab bar up top on a flex tabnavigator component?  I don't want to see the tab bar at all and I don't need to click on it (I have an automated iterator through the tabs).

I have tried .removeChildren, hideElementAt() with no success. Thanks for any input!

Regards,

Joseph

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using a ViewStack container instead.  It's basically a tab navigator without the tabs.

Comment: Great, glad I could help!  Please mark my answer and feel free to upvote it so it applies to my reputation, thanks.  ;)